# Analysis of dependent double for

Tags: algorithm-analysis

Here is the algorithm:

```
int sum = 0
for (int i = 2N; i > 0; i = i / 4) {
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j+=2) {
    sum++
  }
}
```

I figured this would be linearithmic, but it's just linear. I would appreciate seeing a formalized summation and not a qualitative explanation. I have tried doing this but I fail to get linear runtime.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a system behind the magic of algorithm analysis?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis)

Answer (score 1):

The number of iterations is:
$$T = \frac{2N}{2} + \frac{2N}{2 * 4} + \cdots + 1$$

The number of elements in the above formula is $\log_4(2N)$. After simplification, we will have:

$$T = N(1 + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{4^{\log_4(N)}}) = \Theta(N)$$

As $1 + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{4^{\log_4(N)}} < 2$ is a geometric series with step of $\frac{1}{4}$ in asymptotic sense.